# Can't figure out how to change "X5.13.1996" to date class?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have dates listed as `"X5.13.1996"`, representing May 13th, 1996. The class for the date column is currently a character.

When using `mdy` from `lubridate`, it keeps populating `NA`. Is there a code I can use to get rid of the `"X"` to successfully use the code? Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring(date_variable, 2)` to drop the first character from the string.

```r
substring("X5.13.1996", 2)

[1] "5.13.1996"
```

To convert a variable (i.e., column) in your data frame:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dates <- data.frame(
  dt = c("X5.13.1996", "X11.15.2021")
)

dates %>% 
  mutate(converted = mdy(substring(dt, 2)))
```

or, without `dplyr`:

```r
dates$converted <- mdy(substring(dates$dt, 2))
```

**Output:**

```
          dt  converted
1  X5.13.1996 1996-05-13
2 X11.15.2021 2021-11-15
```